# Greyout background onclick of button to display popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where clicking on the button it should greyout the background and the popup msg should be displayed over the greyout area..What im getting now is popup displayed over the alone background is not greyout .
This the script and style im applying

```
<script>
    function deselect() {
        $(".pop").hide();
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#decline").live('click', function () {
            $(".pop").css({ "display": "block", opacity: 0.7, "width": $(document).width(), "height": $(document).height() });
            $(".pop").show();
        });

        $("#close").live('click', function () {
            deselect();
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .messagepop {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        cursor: default;
        display: none;
        margin-top: -39em;
        margin-left: 26em;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        width: 394px;
        z-index: 50;
        padding: 25px 25px 20px;
    }

    .popuptxt {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        text-indent: -15px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .popupbtn {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 135px;
    }

    .messagepop p, .messagepop.div {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
        margin: 8px 0;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
</style>
```

THis html code

```
<input id="decline" type=button name="Decline" value="Decline">
    <div class="messagepop pop">
        <span><font class="popuptxt">By clicking decline, download will not occur, and window will close</font></span>
         <div class="popupbtn">
         <input type="button" name="Ok" class="btn btn-sm  btn-orange" value="<%=labelutils.printTranslatedValues("Ok")%>" onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">
         <input id="close" type="button" name="Cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-gray-dark"  value="<%=labelutils.printTranslatedValues("Cancel")%>">
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think this would qualify as a "Please debug my code" post...? :/

Comment: You likely want a "mask" layer added to the page first (with a partial opacity) then add your "popup" on top of that (with full opacity)

Comment: Thanks tats wat i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was a mess.

- .live() doesn't exist, I replaced that with .on()
- I made your popup `fixed` instead of `absolute` and positioned it correctly
- Instead of using opacity, you should use a semitransparent background color, otherwise the contents of the element also become semi-opaque.
- I also cleaned up your JS a little bit to make it easier to manage.
- I also removed that on-click function you had on that OK-button - I'd advice against using that with user-friendliness in mind

```js
function deselect() {
    $(".pop").hide();
    return false;
}

function select(){
    $(".pop").css({
        display: "block",
        opacity: 1,
        width: $(document).width(),
        height: $(document).height()
    });
    $(".pop").show();
}

$(function () {
    $("#decline").on('click', select);
    $("#close").on('click', deselect);
});
```

```css
.messagepop {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    border:1px solid #999999;
    cursor:default;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:left;
    width:394px;
    z-index:50;
    padding: 25px 25px 20px;
}
.popuptxt {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.popupbtn {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 135px;
}
.messagepop p, .messagepop.div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    margin: 8px 0;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="decline" type=button name="Decline" value="Decline">
    
<div class="messagepop pop">
    <span>
        <font class="popuptxt">
            By clicking decline, download will not occur, and window will close
        </font>
    </span>
    <div class="popupbtn">
        <input type="button" name="Ok" class="btn btn-sm  btn-orange" value="OK">
        <input id="close" type="button" name="Cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-gray-dark" value="Cancel">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info .. Actual thing that I'm using .live() because I'm using jquery version which support tat .. I can't include new script into my page .. And about the position of the popup for my page in order to appear on screen center .. I need to position like tat only .. The scenario I have on the page is different ..

Comment: Well you can't ask people to code for you. You can [read on centering things in css](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) to learn how to do it. Also, comments aren't for thanking - that's what upvoting and the "accept answer" button on the left of people's answers are for.

Answer (score 0):

Found two issues:

1. Looks like the 'live' function you're using doesn't exist in jQuery [since version 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/). So unless it's coming from some other library, that's where you're main problem is.
2. Your `.messagepop` div isn't positioned correctly, and hence doesn't show up on-screen. You want the parent element to have `position:relative`, and then set `position:absolute` on `.messagepop` and `top:0; left:0` to align it correctly.

Rudimentary working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/xj3pL213/